# Picker view's behavior

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

How to implement the picker view's behavior ? I want to make the same magnetism effect on scrolling by keeping focus to the middle item.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
[collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the delegate method `-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`.

The last of those parameters is an in-out `CGPoint` -- it tells you where the scroll will come to rest, and you can make minor adjustments to that point.